# Why does laptop keyboard become unresponsive, fixable only by holding power button for 60 seconds?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard

It's an HP Pavilion x360 laptop (15-bk163dx) with Windows 10. Occasionally (I think when waking from sleep) the keyboard and trackpad will be totally unresponsive. The touchscreen still works, but using it to reboot doesn't help.

In the HP forums, the "solution" is to uninstall the keyboard drivers and let Windows reinstall them, but this hasn't worked for me. What *does* work is holding the power button for 60 seconds, but I have no idea why. I'm glad to know how to temporarily fix the problem, but I'd like to *permanently* fix it. Any guesses as to what's going on?

Comment: Does it work if you wait for 60 seconds without holding power button? I mean is it unresponsive forever?

Comment: It's unresponsive forever, or at least until I hold the power button for 60 seconds. No amount of waiting or regular rebooting makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem hp pavilion x360 with the keyboard and touch-pad not working. My remedy was to boot into safe mode and that fixed it. msconfig->General-> diagnostic startup-> then restart and remember to go back in (MSCONFIG) and choose normal start up or your network wont be back. I also advise do an update. hope it helps someone.

Hp Pavillionx360, win 10